# How to populate in listview data from user class and message class

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have two models are Message and User.The Fragment I receive list of messages and list of users with asyncTaskAdapters and I want display data from these lists on item of listview.

It`s fragmant that should display some messages and users name

```
public class DialogsFragment extends BaseFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

public static final String USER = "user";

private static final String LOG_TAG = DialogsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int LOADER_MESSAGES_ID = 1;

private static final int LOADER_USERS_ID = 2;

long dialogsRequest = -1;
long usersRequest = -1;

private List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Long> usersIdList = new ArrayList<>();

private ListMessagesAdapter mAdapter;
private LoaderManager loaderManager;

@InjectView(R.id.swipe_refresh)
SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;

@InjectView(R.id.footer_conversation)
RelativeLayout mFooter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog_view, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, layout);

    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    loadDialogs();
    return layout;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mAdapter = new ListMessagesAdapter(messageList, userList, getActivity());
    SpeedyQuickReturnListViewOnScrollListener scrollListener =
            new SpeedyQuickReturnListViewOnScrollListener
                    .Builder(getActivity()
                    , QuickReturnViewType.GOOGLE_PLUS).build();

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    scrollListener.registerExtraOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int first, int visibleCount, int total) {
            boolean loadMore = /* maybe add a padding*/
                    first + visibleCount >= total - 1;

            if (loadMore && total > 0) {
                dialogsRequest = getServiceHelper().getDialogs(total - 1, 25);
            }
        }
    });

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Message message = getOnClickMessage(position);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "user id from msg " + message.getUserId());
            User user = User.UTIL.getUser(message.getUserId(), userList);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "user id " + user.getId());

            Intent intentChatActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), HistoryActivity.class);
            intentChatActivity.putExtra(USER, user);

            startActivity(intentChatActivity);
        }
    });
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, " refresh start");
    dialogsRequest = getServiceHelper().getDialogs(0, 25);
    refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onServiceCallback(long requestId, Intent requestIntent, int resultCode, Bundle data) {
    super.onServiceCallback(requestId, requestIntent, resultCode, data);

    if (requestId == dialogsRequest) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "message request complete " + requestId);
        loaderManager.getLoader(LOADER_MESSAGES_ID).forceLoad();
    } else if (requestId == usersRequest) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "user request complete " + requestId);
        loaderManager.getLoader(LOADER_USERS_ID).forceLoad();
    }
}

private LoaderCallbacks<Dialogs> messagesCallbacks = new LoaderCallbacks<Dialogs>() {

    @Override
    public Loader<Dialogs> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        DialogsAsyncLoader messagesLoader = new DialogsAsyncLoader(getActivity());
        return messagesLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Dialogs> loader, Dialogs data) {
        messageList = data.getDialogs();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "message size from request  " + messageList.size());
        if (messageList.size() > 0) {
            String userIds = User.UTIL.getIds(messageList);
            usersRequest = getServiceHelper().getUsers(userIds);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "start userRequest  " + usersRequest);
        }
        mAdapter.setMessages(messageList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Dialogs> loader) {
    }
};

private LoaderCallbacks<List<User>> usersCallback = new LoaderCallbacks<List<User>>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<List<User>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        UsersAsyncLoader usersLoader = new UsersAsyncLoader(getActivity());
        return usersLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<User>> loader, List<User> data) {
        userList = data;
        mAdapter.setUsers(userList);
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<User>> loader) {
        mAdapter.setUsers(new ArrayList<User>());
    }
};

private Message getOnClickMessage(int positon) {
    return messageList.get(positon);
}

private void loadDialogs() {

    if (loaderManager == null) {
        loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    }
    loaderManager.initLoader(LOADER_MESSAGES_ID, null, messagesCallbacks);
    loaderManager.initLoader(LOADER_USERS_ID, null, usersCallback);

    dialogsRequest = getServiceHelper().getDialogs(0, 25);
}
```

I have some idea to use ArrayAdapter

```
 mAdapter = new ListMessagesAdapter(messageList, userList, getActivity());
```

But, when fragment started it displays message without user name and need wait for 5-10 sec to display users . How to synchronize display of these lists ?

**And Important moment:**

> Each message has user_id, so when I got list of message from db with
>   dialogsAsyncLoader I build line that contain user_ids , then I use
>   this line of ids for perform request  for obtain list of users

Comment: You may want to reduce your code sample to a minimal fragment reproducing the problem -- I doubt many people will be willing to read the wall of code you got there.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you load the data from a local db. If this is the case, I would suggest you to load everything in one shot. Define a new object that might look like:

```
UserWithMessages {
    User mUser;
    Message[] mMessages;
}
```

and define your loader to return this type of objects. You can load the data and adapt it to this new type in your background loading method from loader.

Alternatively, if you insist to continue with your current solution, you can ad a simple check in both of your relevant loader' `onLoadFinish` to check if the other one finished and set the adapter with both lists (users and messages) at the same time. Of course, a progress bar of some sort is desirable if you say it takes seconds.